# Using images in Gatsby.js with remark

Tags: gatsby

I'm struggling to add images to remark markdown posts for a gatsby v2 site. My site compiles without complaint, and all the text content from my markdown files is present. However, the images are broken. I've dumped what I *think* are the key config pieces. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my file structure:

```
src - *
      | posts - *
                | post_1 - *
                           | image.png
                           | index.md
```

Here are my plugins -- I've got `gatsby-transformer-remark` set up to use `gatsby-remark-images`.

```
plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
    'gatsby-plugin-offline',
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `src`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/`
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-react-svg',
      options: {
          rule: {
            include: /.svg/
          }
      }
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        plugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {
              maxWidth: 590,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    }
  ]
```

and here's how I'm trying to invoke the image in `index.md`:

```
![My Image](image.png)
```

And lastly `gatsby-node.js`:

```
const { createFilePath } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`)
const path = require('path')

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, getNode, actions: {createNodeField} }) => {
  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    const slug = createFilePath({ node, getNode, basePath: `posts` })
    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: `slug`,
      value: slug
    })
  }
}

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions: {createPage} }) => {
  const result = await graphql(`
    {
      allMarkdownRemark {
        edges {
          node {
            fields {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  console.log(result)
  result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    createPage({
      path: node.fields.slug,
      component: path.resolve('./src/templates/blog-post.js'),
      context: {
        slug: node.fields.slug
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be incompatibly between the version of `gatsby` I was using and the version of gatsby plugins I was using. I was on the v2 `gatsby` line but still using v1 plugins in my package.json

Comment: I have the same problem but looking at plugins `    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.2.15",` seems to be for 2.0 ?

Comment: `
    "gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files": "^2.1.19",
    "gatsby-remark-images": "^3.1.22",
`

Comment: as far as I know, the plugins are versioned independently of the main gatsby project, so just because it's a 2.x.x doesn't necessarily mean it's built for gatsby v2.